# How to get whole URL string(including &,?) in PHP?

Tags: php, string, url

I want to get only URL string in parameter.
So I coded below :

```
//In my HTML file.
<script>
document.write('<iframe id="ifr1" 
src="http://{domain}/prj.php?url=https://www.google.co.kr/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=url+utf8+encoding#sclient=psy-ab&hl=ko&newwindow=1&prmdo=1&tbm=klg&q=google&oq=google&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..0l10.2207859.2208404.3.2208459.6.4.0.1.1.3.496.1353.2-2j1j1.4.0...0.0.O1lbexylHQM&pbx=1&prmdo=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=b8fee9fdb4e7f90&biw=1440&bih=828&a=' +'asdf'+" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0">   </iframe>');
</script>

//In my php file
$message = $_GET['url'];
echo("$message");
```

But I only get 'https://www.google.co.kr/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=3'.

What's wrong?

I want to get whole URL string. Including &,?,or everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you use an encoding into another encoding.

The first is:

```
prj.php?url=[somedata]
```

where [somedata] is an URL with another key/value collection:

```
https://url/etc/search?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

If the url parameter is not *urlencoded* there is no way to distinguish the parameters of `/prj.php` from the parameters of `/search`, it is assumed that *all* the parameters defined with `&key=value&key=value...` syntax belong all to the first page.

The trick is to *url-encode* the url parameter, but how you do it depends on the context.

If the url is dinamically generated via PHP, use the `urlencode()` function.

If your url is hard-coded (not generated via PHP), you can write for yourself a little PHP tool to do the job, or use an online encoder like http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/urlencode/Encode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to encode the url parameter.

Comment: Downvoted because i feel it's not correct, it depends on the context. I'm willing to discuss the issue and remove downvote if motivated.